# Closing another window with javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to close another window when I'm clicking on a specific link. (with javascript)

I have only find a solution where I can close the current window I'm in.

I'm in shop.php and want to close client.php

So when I'm click on the shop.php I will close client.php..

```
<li class="viptab"><a href="{url}/shop" target="_blank" onClick="javascript:window.close('client.php')">SHOP</a><span></span></li>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did JavaScript open up the window? AKA `window.open()`

Comment: Yes, it did. Opened shop and client at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Use  if you want close current window .
`<button onclick="self.close()">Close </button>`

Or use this if you want close child window from parent

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="openWin()">Open </button>
<button onclick="closeWin()">Close </button>

<script>
var myWindow;

function openWin() {
    myWindow = window.open("/client.php", "_blank", "width=500, height=500");
}

function closeWin() {
    myWindow.close();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```