# Need to close secondary window after reload of main window

Tags: javascript

I have a main window that gets reloaded periodically (timer, to change images).  I'd like to open a secondary window and close it later from the main window (open and close buttons).

I tried sessionStorage to keep the window object between reloads, but Firefox still won't let me close the secondary window.  I'm an amateur in javascript so it might be my ignorance.

```
function openwin() {
    let winobj = window.open('tbpage2.html','_blank',
                 'top=50,left=100,width=300,height=300');
    sessionStorage.setItem('page2winobj', winobj);
}
function closewin() {
    let winobj = sessionStorage.getItem('page2winobj');
    winobj.close();
}
```

Error is 'TypeError: winobj.close is not a function'.
Firefox console shows the window object in sessionStorage, but close() apparently can't use it.

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25686771/closing-another-window-with-javascript

Comment: thanks, it's a little different though - in my case, a page reload happens and the window object is lost.

Comment: You can only store data, strings and such like that. You can't store window objects

Comment: This isn't possible. Only the script that opened a window can close it. If you reload the page, it's no longer the same script.

Comment: Reload your body with AJAX, so you don't have a true refresh. Then close your window without having to use localstorage, which isn't possible to use anyhow as I already stated.

Comment: OK, I appreciate the comments.  It is apparently not going to be possible with my app.